# Akka pattern for instantiating an actor only if the entity it represents has previously been created?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

How can I only load an actor if it has previously been formally created following domain rules? Everything I've seen using `actorOf` and persistence always creates an empty instance and then applies the [possibly empty] set of events that have occurred, whereas I would prefer to make empty instances unrepresentable. Is there a standard approach for requiring a "created" event and otherwise triggering failure via "not found"?

My thinking is to have one actor instance for each entity in the system, but my expectation is that less than 10% of the entities will be actively needed at any given time so I'm trying to avoid loading the entire set just to check validity when handling a request.

I'm new to Akka and event sourcing in general so if I'm thinking about things from an unhelpful perspective I'm open to any alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about PersistentActors.
There is no api for pre persisting state outside of the PersistentActor. The idea is that actor keeps track of his state for himself. There is no profit of empty actors, actors should keep some state so when you initialise it via `actorOf` it should have kind of state `Created`. On the other hand you should not think it has saved its state until it reports to creator that it was persisted.

Persistent actors are loaded passively into the memory only when you initialise them explicitly, so all the entities won't be loaded at startup. If you want to passivate them you can stop the actors or invoke `setReceiveTimeout` method on actor's context.

Comment: Thanks. Yes to the `PersistentActor`. The thought of having "created" as part of the actor's state crossed my mind - is this the proper/best approach? My concern is that requiring the "supervisor" to check the created state of its children seems to break encapsulation. I would prefer the child instance trigger failure during loading/initialization - are you aware of something in the actor lifecycle that allows encapsulation of these sort of pre-condition checks? I'll have a similar scenario on the other end when it comes to deletion.

Comment: If you do not have external state (for example database) where you can check the existence of actor's entity for sure you then can only try to initialise the actor and then send the current state of the actor from the actor itself to the one which is able to check whether its state is right or not. It depends on the particular case how is better to check (by supervisor or by some state checker actor) and who should stop it in case of wrong state.

Comment: Checking a database would solve needing to keep the list of valid entities inside the supervisor, but I wouldn't want that out-of-band logic. Having a "state checker" actor just shifts the responsibility to some other third party and I'm back where I started. So is there no way for an actor initialization to indicate failure? Or perhaps I'm thinking of this whole thing wrong and I really shouldn't  be tying an actor to an entity instance, in which case what approach should I use?

Comment: It is very abstract, the implementation depends on particular case. 
To indicate failure you can just throw an exception in the actor and override the SupervisionStrategy of the parent actor. You can also subscribe for Terminated message from child by invoking `context.watch(childActorRef)` in the parent